# React and Typescript functional component can be 1 of 3 interfaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a component that can use 1 of 3 interfaces that is able to determine what interface based on what props are passed to it.

```
interface CommonProps {
  label: string;
  icon?: React.ComponentType;
  role?: string;
}

interface ButtonProps extends CommonProps {
  handleOnClick: () => void;
  selected?: boolean;
  largeVariant?: boolean;
}

interface LinkProps {
  to: string;
  openInNewTab?: boolean;
}

interface HrefProps {
  href: string;
  openInNewTab?: boolean;
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps | LinkProps | HrefProps> = props => {
  const { label, handleOnClick, to, href, icon, openInNewTab } = props;
  if (to || href) {
    const Component = to ? Link : 'a';
    return (
      <StyledButton
        component={Component}
        target={openInNewTab ? '_blank' : undefined}
        onMouseDown={(e: any) => {
          href && pushMatomoExternalLink(e, href);
        }}
        {...props}
      >
        {icon && <StyledIcon icon={icon} />}
        {label}
      </StyledButton>
    );
  }
  return (
    <StyledButton onClick={handleOnClick} {...props}>
      {icon && <StyledIcon icon={icon} />}
      {label}
    </StyledButton>
  );
};
```

Desired Behavior including errors I would expect to see.

```
<Button label="View Report" handleOnClick={action('BUTTON CLICKED')} />
```

Would infer the interface is ButtonProps

```
<Button label="View Report" selected />
```

> TypeScript error: Property 'handleOnClick' is missing in type '{
>   label: string; selected: boolean;}' but required in type 'ButtonProps'.

```
<Button label="View Report" openInNewTab />
```

Would infer that interface would be LinkProps or HrefProps

> Property 'to' is missing in type '{ label: string; openInNewTab: boolean; }' but required in type 'LinkProps'.
>
> Property 'href' is missing in type '{ label: string; openInNewTab: boolean;  }' but required in type 'HrefProps'.

```
<Button label="View Report" href="/" openInNewTab />
```

Would infer the interface is HrefProps

Comment: Please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org) so that others can see your issue.  Right now I don't have definitions for `Link` or `StyledButton` so I'm not sure if my suggestion will work for you.  Nor do I understand what you mean by "infer"; where specifically would you like the compiler to infer the interface?  The compiler's behavior here looks reasonable to me; can you elaborate on what you expect vs what is happening?

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion. I'll make some changes to the examples after work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your issue is; if I take your exact code except for the errorful implementation of `Button` (assuming that this implementation is not needed for a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), the compiler gives exactly the errors you want to see

```
declare const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps | LinkProps | HrefProps>;
<Button label="View Report" handleOnClick={console.log} />;
// okay

<Button label="View Report" selected />; 
// Property 'handleOnClick' is missing in type '{ label: string; selected: true; }' 
// but required in type 'ButtonProps'.(2322)

<Button label="View Report" openInNewTab />;
// Property 'href' is missing in type '{ label: string; openInNewTab: true; }' 
// but required in type 'HrefProps'.(2322)

<Button label="View Report" href="/" openInNewTab />;
// okay
```

If this is not as you expect, or if the issue is actually with the implementation of `Button`, then please edit your question to specify what your issue is, including a reproducible example that shows exactly what you are seeing and how it differs from what you expect to see.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUI8AHYxZQF5ZwDCJICCwAKxMOgDejOHAA2yAEZZZALjioYUVgHN6DGcFxCA-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-sDar+GtDOuxuP+gIUMcdCZdydgabIqPFeYLcCLqBLLzLE8rZGru9rXx6zjU8fnPRQWygNs407eNE17eBB2HUdvwrKcxQlXl5yXVd1y9GdfQAgMVQPI9oDDUp4WVO0T1cHEwPxS9Y27V13ScIA)

Answer (score 0):

The one possible solution is to use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to check what type of props is passed. A type guard should have a logic to find out what type of passed props it got. In the code below `propsIsButtonProps`, `propsIsLinkProps` and `propsIsHrefProps` are type guards.

I have simplified your code to showcase the main idea.

```
function propsIsButtonProps (props: any): props is ButtonProps {
  return props.selected !== undefined;
}
function propsIsLinkProps (props: any): props is LinkProps {
  return props.to !== undefined;
}
function propsIsHrefProps (props: any): props is HrefProps {
  return props.href !== undefined;
}

export const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps | LinkProps | HrefProps> = props => {
  if (propsIsLinkProps(props) || propsIsHrefProps(props)) {
    const Component = propsIsLinkProps(props) ? 'div' : 'a';
    return (
      <Component
        target={props.openInNewTab ? '_blank' : undefined}
        onMouseDown={(e: any) => {
          propsIsHrefProps(props) && pushMatomoExternalLink(e, props.href);
        }}
        {...props}
      >
        {props.label}
      </Component>
    );
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={props.handleOnClick} {...props}>
      {props.label}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Working demo is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/props-as-union-ogf0y)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about function overloading, right ? This can be easily done in languages like C / C++, but with typescript it is kind of hard. This is because at the end typescript code converted in to JavaScript and in JavaScript function overloading is impossible.

Here's a possible solution for the scenario.

```
interface CommonProps {
  label: string;
  icon?: string;
  role?: string;
}

export interface ButtonProps extends CommonProps {
  kind: "button-props";
  handleOnClick: () => void;
  selected?: boolean;
  largeVariant?: boolean;
}

export interface LinkProps {
  kind: "link-props";
  to: string;
  openInNewTab?: boolean;
}

export interface HrefProps {
  kind: "href-props";
  href: string;
  openInNewTab?: boolean;
}

type Types = HrefProps | LinkProps | ButtonProps ;

const Button : React.FC<Types> = props => {
    switch(props.kind){
        case "button-props" :
            // some code
        case "href-props" :
            // some code
        case "link-props" :
            // some code
        default :
            return;
    }
}
```

And now in your parent component,

```
import { ButtonProps, LinkProps, HrefProps } from './Button.component.ts';

function Parent = (props) => {
   const propsToChild : ButtonProps = {// data object with type ButtonProps}
   return (
     <Button {...propsToChild}/>
   )
}
```